# How do I know how much weight I should be lifting with dumbells?

Tags: exercise, weightlifting, weights

I was just given a set of weights - adjustable weight dumbells -  as a present, but I have no idea what sort of weights/how many reps I should be doing in order to achieve the best results.

I'm looking to increase the strength of my arms and wrists (lean strength?), and hope it can increase my strength for playings sports like tennis, squash and so on.

Is there a rule of thumb for weights/reps I should be aiming at?

Comment: This is very broad and difficult to answer as asked. Please add more detail to the question, in particular what your goals are: does "best results" mean you want to gain muscle bulk, or gain lean strength, or...? Also, knowing specifically what came in your set of weights would be helpful. Is it just some plates and a long bar, or is there more to it?

Comment: Will update the question; as you can see I don't know much about the topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, you'll want to pick a set of exercises to do and learn how to do them with proper form. Then you can start increasing the weight and set a schedule.

In general, I would recommend a full-body workout that hits all the muscle groups with a few compound lifts. However, I'll try to craft a workout for you here that fits your stated goal with the equipment that you have.

For exercises, try:

- [Dumbell curls](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vm18W1LIZ9A)
- [Tricep extensions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRiJVZDpdL0)
- [Forearm reverse curls](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pVt5lGKj8s) (make sure to do these *after* the regular curls above)

You can experiment more as you get comfortable, but this might be a good workout to start with. You can do it as often as you feel energetic and not sore, but a good starting goal might be 2x/week; err on the side of an extra day of rest rather than straining yourself because muscles grow when they recover. I would suggest doing 3-5 sets of 8 reps of each with a couple minutes rest between each set.

As far as how much weight to use, you need to first use a very light weight and make sure that you have your form down (pay attention to the tips and the motions in the videos). When you're comfortable with the movements, add weight for each exercise gradually. If you're doing 8 reps per set, then you'll want a weight at which you'd fail after perhaps 10-12 reps.

A few other hints that will help pay off down the road:

- Keep your core tight when doing these exercises
- Squeeze the bar when you're lifting, especially for the dumbell curls.
- Lower the weight slowly; these are called *negatives* and can be as beneficial as lifting the weight up

Comment: Great answer - thanks very much for this - a really good starting point for me. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

For strength, 3 work sets of 5 reps is suggested by [Starting Strength](http://startingstrength.com/).  5x5 is recommended at [StrongLifts 5x5](http://stronglifts.com/).  Work sets do not include warm up sets.  For warm-up, you can do 3 sets at 25%, 50%, 75% of work weight with about

If you are just starting then begin with a small weight to get used to the motion and improve form.  At every workout that you succeed your work sets, increase weight by the smallest increment you can.  This is the most important part: *If you want to get stronger, you must lift heavier weight.*

Don't neglect your shoulders for tennis and squash.  Do Overhead Presses and Bench Presses.  http://www.exrx.net/Exercise.html

Answer (score 0):

There are no general rules as such.

To get toned muscular arm u need to focus on what u are doing. Set your self a goal. If u want to have a muscular arms then concentrate on reps and sets and weight u are using.

To begin with try

Beginner level
4 sets with dumbbells
1st set 4 kg 10 rep
2nd set 4 kg 10 rep
3rd set 4 kg 10 rep
4th set 4 kg 10 rep

once u get the technique and posture right ,We advance into next level

Intermediate level

4 sets with dumbbells
1st set 4 kg 10 rep
2nd set 6 kg 10 rep
3rd set 8 kg 10 rep
4th set 10 kg 10 rep

do this until u have attained the final objective of 10
kg 10 rep

advance level

2 sets with dumbbells warm up level to get that blood flowing into your vains

1st set 4 kg 15 rep
2nd set 6 kg 15 rep

3rd set would be your best weight, with which u can do 10 rep

4th set would be slightly heavy to challenge your self for your personnel best of 10 reps with next heavy weight.

Make sure u rest in between sets for about 90 sec, Proper breathing technique posture, positives ( when u are lifting up ) and negative ( when u are bringing your weight down ), make sure you are not cheating while lifting.

If u can log your proress using excel sheet on a day to day basics and compare it with your weight recorded on daily basis u can analyse how things have improved and u may want to push it more further