# How much dumbell weight will i lift?

Tags: weight-gain, dumbbells

My height is 155cm and weight is 36.5kg. i posted it if someone can help me out. I need to know how much weight i can lift given that data or their any other app that calculate it. I am underweight and they say 5lbs is most starting point. So can i start on 5lbs or lighter weights( I want to start using dumbells only)?

PS: I dont want to test based on what can i lift but on scientific/mathematical calculation based on my weight and height.

i saw this
[link](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/521/how-do-i-know-how-much-weight-i-should-be-lifting-with-dumbells),but this doesnt answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no calculation for how much you will lift.

Start lifting small weights for a specific number of repetitions. When that becomes to easy, add more weight.

Also, 36kg is technically underweight according to your BMI, so try and add some mass.

Comment: How much weight sir do you see i must lift? 4lbs or 3lbs? I need suggestion please.

Comment: **Ummm... 3?** I don't know. Start at the lowest you can and if thats too easy increase the weight.

Comment: ok sir, thanks for entertaining my question. :)